# Inject fields in a generic class

Tags: android, dagger-2

I have an Activity of the following form:

```
public class MyActivity<T extends AbstractDescriptionItem> extends BaseActivity[...]
```

when I define:

```
@ContributesAndroidInjector
abstract MyActivity contributeMyActivity();
```

I get this error:

```
error: [Dagger/MembersInjection] [dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T)] Cannot inject members into raw type com.test MyActivity
```

if I try:

```
@ContributesAndroidInjector
abstract MyActivity<AbstractDescriptionItem> contributeMyActivity();
```

I get

```
error: @ContributesAndroidInjector methods cannot return parameterized types
```

Is there any way to inject dependencies in MyActivity without changing the architecture?

Answer (score 1):

The solution I came up with is to implement the different cases of the Activity/Fragment with type parameters and contribute the implementations. It will be something like this for your case:

```
public abstract class MyActivity<T extends AbstractDescriptionItem> extends BaseActivity[...]
```

Let's say you have a `BookDescriptionItem` class extending `AbstractDescriptionItem` :

```
public class BookDescriptionActivity extends MyActivity<BookDescriptionItem>
```

Finally, contribute the implementations:

```
@ContributesAndroidInjector
abstract BookDescriptionActivity contributeBookDescriptionActivity();
```